# Azure WebJobs SDK Accessing Queue Properties

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Is it possible to receive the full Azure Service Bus Queue BrokeredMessage when using the Azure WebJobs SDK triggers? I also need to be able to tell the service bus queue when the message has been handled or hasn't ben handled successfully.  There is a new Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.ServiceBus nuget package, but I haven't seen any documentation on how to use it.  The examples I have seen are for storage queues which are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can bind the message to BrokeredMessage. Look at the following example https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/ServiceBus

Comment: That is example what I was looking for.  Thanks